# Firemonkey form show in full screen on Android

Tags: android, delphi, modal-dialog, firemonkey

I do my own "InputQuery" form.

```
procedure TForm3SApp.recAppelerNumeroClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   FInputQuery: TFormInputQuery;
begin
   FInputQuery := TFormInputQuery.Create(Self);
   FInputQuery.Width   := ClientWidth - 40;
   FInputQuery.Title   := 'Appeler';
   FInputQuery.Message := 'Voulez-vous appeler le ' + FNumeroUrgence.Names[FiNumeroUrgence] + ' ?';

   FInputQuery.ShowModal(procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
   begin
      if ModalResult = mrOK then
         Appeler(FNumeroUrgence.Names[FiNumeroUrgence]);
      FInputQuery.DisposeOf;
   end
```

On my TFormInputQuery, I set :

```
BorderStyle = None
BorderIcons = [] (none)
FormStyle = StayOnTop
FullScreen = False
Position = ScreenCenter
```

On Windows all is ok, but when I open my app on Android, my TFormInputQuery is shown in full screen, any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Use a TRectangle instead of a form.

Comment: I wanted use a form because I already have a PageControl with a lot of TabItem, and a lot of TRectangle..

Comment: Why can't the form be full-screen? What difference does it make to you?